# Update file in database and upload file

Tags: php

thank you in advance for your help, i need to make a system were i can upload and update a file into my database record. To do so i made this code but for some reason i cant seem to see what i have done wrong i can update the "status and so on" but the file is not uploaded into my desired directory and the record is missing in my database too, so all the rest works just fine, except the file itself, does not get updated. Here is my code, again thanks in advance!

```
<?php
                    if(isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) 
                    {
                    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filename']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
                    require 'modules/conn.php';
                    $target = "../account-files/";
                    $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']);
                    }


                    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
                    $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
                    $counts = $_REQUEST['counts'];
                    $Filename=basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']);
                    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE files SET id ='".$_POST['id']."', status ='".$_POST['status']."', counts ='".$_POST['counts']."', Filename ='".$_POST['Filename']."' WHERE id = '".$id."'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
                    header("location: ../my-account/");
                    }
                    ?>
```

Everything else gets updated in my database, but as i said, the file and the record of the file name does not, also its not uploaded into my directory. Please help me, an example would be very much appreciated.

Updated code i can get the records into the database but still no upload into the directory.

```
$target = "../account-files/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']);
if(isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) 
{
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filename']['tmp_name'], $target);
require 'modules/conn.php';
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];
$status = $_REQUEST['status'];
$counts = $_REQUEST['counts'];
$Filename=basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']);
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE files SET id = $id, status = '$status', counts = $counts , Filename = '$Filename' WHERE id = '$id'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
header("location: ../my-account/");
}
```

This last solution is correct i hope i can contribute also to other members, see solution credits bellow at the correct reply to my post, that guy rocks! Thumbs up so what was the error? Simple, the path i had was wrong...

this one is wrong:

```
$target = "../account-files/";
```

This is correct and fixes all

```
$target = "account-files/";
```

Comment: did you check if php actually has permissions to write to the desired directory? you could check by using `file_put_contents($target,'it works!')`

Comment: It has my friend, checked that @ManuelOtto, in fact this code its for the front view, because in the back i made a system to add also files and it works, this one, i need just to update a file, like for example, in the back they request a file, and in the front they add the file and update 2 fields as described. Thank you in advance

Comment: is `$target` actually defined before you make the call to `move_uploaded_file`? I see you define it after that, but not before.

Comment: I have placed after that but still updates all the other fields and no changes i cant seem to get the upload working and the record to be updated into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really have the POST['Filename']? I think you should put the variables in you query instead of .POST

Try the code below:

```php
  if(isset($_POST['submit_btn'])) 
  {
   $target_dir = "../account-files/";
   $target_file = $target_dir . basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']);
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filename']['tmp_name'], $target_file);
   require 'modules/conn.php';

   $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
   $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
   $counts = $_REQUEST['counts'];
   $Filename=basename( $_FILES['Filename']['name']);
   $query = mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE files SET id = $id, status = 
  '$status', counts = $counts , Filename = '$Filename' WHERE id = 
  '".$id."'") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  header("location: ../my-account/");
 }
```

And also please make sure that you have the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your form tag.

Comment: Going to give it a try on that one my friend. I keep you posted and updated in a few minutes @jqueryy

Comment: Now this code do the trick, updates the database with the record, what i cant get its the upload of the file itself, but it did really helped. At least the record is there in the Database, any suggestions?

Comment: try removing if() on move_uploaded_file, see my updated answer and try it again @PedroCarvalho

Comment: also as suggested on the other answer, you can remove the id = $id on SET, you don't have to update the ID, you'll just need it in the where clause

Comment: I also noticed that the $target variable is below the move uploaded file function, you'll have to set the value of the $target variable first

Comment: I changed the code, still i can make the record in the database but no upload so i get a 404 if i follow that link, going to paste all the code bellow here

Comment: I edited my code my friend, please check on top the updated version

Comment: @PedroCarvalho I updated my answer, try the whole block

Comment: I did my friend, still get the same issue, its so strange i do get the record, but the file does not exist..

Comment: No error my friend, blank output, all works perfectly, but no upload at all

Comment: Have you check your <form> tag if it has the "enctype="multipart/form-data" ?

Comment: <form action="" method="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: <form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" autocomplete="off" action="<?php echo($_SERVER["REDIRECT_SITE_HTMLROOT"]); ?>/account-request-updated/">

Comment: strange, can you try creating a test folder on the same directory and try to move the file there?

Comment: Of course, doing it right now, lets call it test so the path is going to be ../account-files/test/

Comment: is your php script is on the same folder as the upload folder?

Comment: No its in the main root, inside the root i got that folder (account-files)

Comment: My friend my code was wrong in the path you have it spot on, instead of using the ../account-files/ should be account-files/ issue fixed, thumbs up, you are the boss! Thank you so much it worked perfectly both are inserted and updated

Comment: I have updated my post, all credits to you my friend, you rule!

Answer (score 0):

You make some mistakes:

1. how you can upload the file first and then determine the target
2. why are you updating id? while id is its primary key

i

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_btn'])){
   $target = "../account-files/"; 
   $fname = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
   if(!empty($target) && !empty($fname)){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], $target.$fname);
   }
}
```

Comment: The ID i need to update the record in the database, i am going to test your solution my friend, i see i made a few errors here @Ryan, going to give it a try on that one i keep you posted in a few minutes.

Comment: To update the filename, you only need to use `$fname`, and my suggestion, you do not update the primary key and make it a habit to create variables with lowercase letters. good luck my friend